# SharePoint List - Max value between 3 columns of same record

Tags: list, sharepoint, max

I have 3 columns defined as Availability, Confidentiality, and Integrity.
Each column can have value between 0 and 3.
I would like to get the maximum value from this 3 columns.
I have created a calculated field called Max SC with following formula:

=IF(AND(Availability>Confidentiality),Availability>Integrity),Availability,IF(AND(Confidentiality>Availability,Confidentiality>Integrity),Confidentiality,IF(AND(Integrity>Availability,Integrity>Confidentiality),Integrity)))

Unfortunately I am getting error message "*The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported*"

Any support would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:
IF(AND(Availability=Confidentiality=Integrity),Availability,IF(AND(Availability=Confidentiality,Availability>Integrity),Availability,IF(AND(Availability=Confidentiality, Availability<Integrity),Integrity,IF(AND(Confidentiality=Integrity,Confidentiality>Availability),Confidentiality,Availability))))

Answer (score 0):

You added an extra right parentheses in the formula.

Here is the formula:

=IF(AND(Availability>Confidentiality,Availability>Integrity),Availability,IF(AND(Confidentiality>Availability,Confidentiality>Integrity),Confidentiality,IF(AND(Integrity>Availability,Integrity>Confidentiality),Integrity)))

Result:

[image]